# providing user an excel file so that they may download it to their system in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can we allow user to download an excel file in react redux or even vanilla javascript ?I don't want to use jquery for this.How can the same be achieved with react or vanialla javascript?Where should we keep our downloadable file ?
I just came across this requirement with no idea but on googling I got results which required jquery.

I came across this w3school link but it does not support IE .

Comment: Try appending "vanilla javascript" or "-jquery" to your search queries.

Comment: Is jquery too heavy?

Answer (score 0):

You can download excel in reactjs this way:

```
<a ref={(ref) => downloadRef = ref}>
    <Button onClick={()=> handleExportList()}>
        Export
    </Button>
</a>

let downloadRef;
  const handleExportList = () => {
   let excelExportUrl = `http://......`;
   downloadRef.href = excelExportUrl;
   downloadRef.download = 'download';
}
```

Comment: cannot read property href of undefined.i ma getting this error now .

Comment: @satyajeetjha did you add ref={(ref) => downloadRef = ref}  in <a> tag ?